# Panoramic projections of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, hyperbolic-geometry, projection

What are possible interesting panoramic projections of the hyperbolic plane?

I am puzzling with projections of the hyperbolic plane and at the moment specifically with panoramic ones.(my term, maybe there is a better or more frequently used
term, maybe that is why I could not find much about it)

I define panoramic projections (again my term, maybe other terms are better) as a projection where there is a dedicated point $O$ and all lines trough point $O$ become parallel vertical lines in the projection.

And a dedicated direction (in this case the positive y axis , that has its image on the $h = 0$ axis.
The negative y axis has its image up side down on the $ h=\pm 1 $ lines

So taking the origin as the dedicated point $O$ and a point $A = (x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of the point in the Poincare disk model.

the projection of $A$ to $(h,v)$ becomes a modified version of
$$ h = \frac{\arctan (x / y) }{\pi} $$
for the horizontal coordinate,so that it goes from $-1$ to $1$

And some function $$ v = f(x,y), (f(x,y) \ge 0 ) $$ for the vertical coordinate.

The result is a projection of the complete hyperbolic plane as if it is seen from the origin, and the viewer there can only look forward and rotate. And the rotation becomes a translation to the left or right in the image. (So all libes through $O$ become parallel lines)

My panoramic projection is comparable to a cylindrical projection in spherical geometry where the dedicated position is a point on the axis , for examples

Mercator projection ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection

Equirectangular projection ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection )

and many others, (in each of these examples the designated point is the south pole)

My question is:
What are interesting choices for the function $f(x,y) $?

What is the function $f(x,y)$ to make the projection:

- equidistant?
- equal area?
- limited (there is a maximum of v)
- gnomonic  (if possible)
- conformal (if possible)
- otherwise interesting?

Maybe i just used the wrong search terms but I could not find a good introductory text on this. If you know one please let me know.

Comment: I'd work in "clockwise" polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ with $\theta=0$ along the positive $y$-axis and$-\pi<\theta\leq\pi$, so that $h(r,\theta)=\theta/\pi$ is in $(-1, 1]$ and the Poincare metric has a $\theta$-independent expression. Writing $v = f(r,\theta)$ (no absolute value, and not the same as $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ in the question), it looks feasible to calculate the "pullback" of the Euclidean metric in the strip $(-1, 1]\times(-\infty,\infty)$ and prospectively read off the properties of interest in terms of $f$ and its first derivative. <> I have not tried to work out details.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your definition of panoramic projection? When you say 'become vertical lines', do you mean that the projections are assymptotic to vertical lines? Do you have an example picture?

Comment: Elaborated a bit hopes it makes it clearer (and not more confusing)

Comment: Maybe the paper "[Models and projections of hyperbolic geometry](https://roguetemple.com/z/hyper/models.php)" by Zeno Rogue can be helpful.

Comment: I do not understand the question (your definition is too vague for me) but what would be the advantage of having such a map? Since it will have to be only partially defined on the hyperbolic plane, it will be inferior to the standard models of hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: @AlexRavsky all projections mentioned there are not panoramic (the player is on a regular tile) while in a panoramic projection the player would be on a line or a tile being the width of the whole projection.

Comment: @MoisheKohan i agree my definition  is vague but that is because for a start I only use one constraint on the projection (that ig is panoramic) while there are probably many variations of it. What advantages it might have, maybe none, maybe some, maybe some unexpected ones. Probably a conformal panoramic projection is interesting,  but does it exist?